# Jupyter Notebook Fails Save when Function has a return

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

I'm not doing much fancy here,  I have a function:

```
def to_onehot(labels, nclasses):
    outlabels = np.zeros(len(labels), nclasses)
    for i,l in enumerate(labels):
         outlabels[i,l] = 1
    return outlabels
```

For some reason in the Jupyter note book (Python2) if I have this return, I get a crazy error: "UnicodeDecodeError: utf8 codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 3924, invalid start byte.

Ok, thats really weird, because I'm not even trying to run the code cell.  If I simply delete the return statement, all seems happy.  Ok, well I mean I could do that, but I kinda need to return this matrix.

Any thoughts out there?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you copy-pasted the return statement from somewhere else? Try to fix the encoding of the  "return outlabels".

Comment: nah, hand typed on a standard U.S. keyboard.  I have noticed that all my markdown goes into a weird format as well...

Comment: I like the thinking, but i hand typed everything in the notebook.

Comment: You can try to convert the file to utf-8 and see if it's working.  Like this `iconv -c -t UTF-8 < input_file > output_file`. And see if the problem resolves. Since all your files get corrupted, then maybe you have an issue with your locale.

Comment: I'm starting to think the issue is not actually utf-8.  I'm able to delete, re-add, and use the save button after fixing some of the weird formatting it does and it saves from there.  But then it goes back into that weird state occasionally